# How can I force my module to load after another?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, extensions

I want my Magento extension to load after another extension has already loaded. Anyone know how to do that?

Normally I'd use the 'depends' tag in the etc/modules/ xml file but that causes errors if the depended on module is not installed, and that's not what I want.

I also don't want to rely on alphabetical loading and rename my module.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ruled out almost all options...

However you don't have to rename your module. The load order depends on the name of the xml file that loads your module. Convention is that the name of the module declaration file matches your company and module name. If you break with this convention you can get your module loaded after another one instead of
`app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml` use
`app/etc/modules/company_Module.xml` (lower case alphabet comes later) or even
`app/etc/modules/z.xml`

If you could mention why you need to affect the load order someone might be able to provide a solution for that particular issue.

Comment: Renaming the module case works for me! Thanks.